# Django no dirige a la URL correcta

Tags: python, django

**views.py**

```
class PartnerListView(ListView):
    model = Partner
    template_name = 'contacts/partner_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context  = super(PartnerListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()

        if self.kwargs['estil'] == 'lst':
            context['line'] = True
        elif self.kwargs['estil'] == 'kbn':
            context['line'] = False

        if self.kwargs['cat'] == 'cat':
            context['groupByCat'] = True
        else:
            context['groupByCat'] = False
       return context


class PartnerCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Partner
    form_class = PartnerForm
    template_name = 'contacts/partner_create_form.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'contacts'  
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^list/(?P<estil>lst|kbn)/(?P<cat>cat|alf)/$',    PartnerListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    url(r'^create/$', PartnerCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PartnerDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', PartnerUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', PartnerDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
]
```

**template**

```
{% if groupByCat %}
<button type="button" name="" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:4px" onclick=location.href="{% url 'contacts:list' estil='lst' cat='cat' %}">

<img src="{% static 'images/icons/icons8-list-24.png' %}" alt="" />

</button>

<button type="button" name="" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:4px" onclick=location.href="{% url 'contacts:list' estil='kbn' cat='cat' %}">

<img src="{% static 'images/icons/icons8-grid-24.png' %}" alt="" />

</button>

{% else %}
<button type="button" name="" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:4px" onclick=location.href="{% url 'contacts:list' estil='lst' cat='alf' %}">

<img src="{% static 'images/icons/icons8-list-24.png' %}" alt="" />

</button>
<button type="button" name="" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:4px"
onclick=location.href="{% url 'contacts:list' estil='kbn' cat='alf' %}">
<img src="{% static 'images/icons/icons8-grid-24.png' %}" alt="" />
</button>
{% endif %}
{% if line %}
<button type="button" name="" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:4px"
onclick=location.href="{% url 'contacts:list' estil='lst' cat='cat' %}">
<img src="{% static 'images/icons/icons8-user-groups-24.png' %}" alt="" />
</button>
<button type="submit" name="" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:4px"
onclick=location.href="{% url 'contacts:list' estil='lst' cat='alf' %}">
<img src="{% static 'images/icons/icons8-alpha-24.png' %}" alt="" />
</button>
{% else %}
<button type="button" name="" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:4px"
onclick=location.href="{% url 'contacts:list' estil='kbn' cat='cat' %}">
<img src="{% static 'images/icons/icons8-user-groups-24.png' %}" alt="" />
</button>
<button type="submit" name="" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:4px"
onclick=location.href="{% url 'contacts:list' estil='kbn' cat='alf' %}">
<img src="{% static 'images/icons/icons8-alpha-24.png' %}" alt="" />
</button>
{% endif %}
<button type="button" name="" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:4px"
onclick=location.href="{% url 'contacts:create' %}">
<img src="{% static 'images/icons/add-new-24.png' %}" alt="" />
</button>
```

Como podeis ver, la primera URL tiene 2 argumentos y la siguiente no tiene. La primera URL funciona correctamente, pero al llamar a la segunda URL con un botón con `{% url 'contacts:create' %}`, Django intenta renderizar la primera, al no recibir los parámetros esperados, lanza el error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /contacts/create/
Reverse for 'list' with keyword arguments '{'estil': 'kbn'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['contacts/list/(?P<estil>.+)/(?P<cat>.+)/$']
```

¿Cómo consigo que llame a la URL correcta?

Comment: Deberías poner `{% url 'create' %},` simplemente, ya que ese es el nombre (que declaraste en urls.py como `name='create'`) de la vista que querés llamar. Ahí te está diciendo que probó con yendo a /contacts/create y esa URL no existe, vos solo tenés /create

Comment: Las URLs no se renderizan en el orden en el que las has definido en la lista, se usan expresiones regulares para decidir cuál de ellas es la que se tiene que usar. Me parece que debe haber un error en tu template, ¿puedes mostrarlo en tu pregunta?

Comment: Se que no se renderizan en orden, la question és que las url tienen nombre, y que estoy llamando a la url llamada "create", pero django busca la url  llamada "list": Tampoco es un problema de la template, ya que, aunque escriba la url direcatmente en la barra de direcciones, sigue sin funcionar.